# defining a microservices architecture for an intern management system

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

i have this project of developping An *intern management system* where **supervisors** can create and assign tasks to interns. **Interns** can update the status of their tasks. Another actor **Admin** can manage intern desks by assigning specific desks to interns. And using an authentication system”

i don't have a large knowledge about spring microservices, I only developped monolothic app with MVC architecture.

Can you please help me define each service. i don't want to break it down to a lot of services, just enough to validate my project.

thank you

i did some research, i had this idea of break in it into an authentication service, an intern service, a task service and a desk service. but to start coding, i didn't know if it's right, what are the models for each services, because we can find the intern exists in all the services services...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, there might be multiple solutions depending on your requirements and the way you think and approach the problem at hand. I don't think microservices are really needed for the requirements that you have mentioned. But since it is a necessity here, you can do the following:

1. Build an UI
2. UI will connect to the Login microservice
3. Implement a Login microservice which will authenticate the user and return a response containing the role of the logged in user back to the UI.
4. Have another microservice named 'Task'. Create and secure the respective APIs to perform all the mentioned tasks and secure the APIs with role based access (for supervisors, interns and admins). This can be achieved by Spring Security (there are multiple other libraries too).

Adding more microservices will only increase the redundancy in my honest opinion. It is nice to keep it short and simple.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. you're right, monolithic arch is enough, but i'm required to use ms arch, it's for studies .  let's ignore the authentication microservice now, can we discuss the fourth point? at the beginning i need to build at least the task, intern and desk microservices. in monolith arch it was easy with relational database, association tables and jpa annotations but now i'm blocked, i don't know what entities for each service, example : how the supervisor gonna attach an intern object to a task object if the intern entity is in another microservice , (is it the same as importing packages?)